# How can get strings value about .m3u8 or .ts file from event of video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to handle string value from .m3u8 or .ts file(below) on Javascript.

Can I access this information(converted string or JSON)through video tag event?
or is there any method?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3.84
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:3.84,
some_url/1/some_file1.ts?from=0&to=3840
#EXTINF:1.728,
some_url/1/some_file2.ts?from=0&to=3840
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Did you try anything that is not working (to avoid us from repeating known info)? You can use `Fetch` API to load file as String (since m3u8 is just a text document). The file must exist in same server /folder as the HTML (or else it gives CORS error, so just use PHP instead to load the m3u8 bytes, if possible to try).

Answer (score 0):

you can go through https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#ploader
and change the class this way to get the data you displayed.

```js
class pLoader extends Hls.DefaultConfig.loader{
    constructor(config) {
     super(config);
     var load = this.load.bind(this);
     this.load = function (context, config, callbacks) {
      if (context.type == 'level') {
        var onSuccess = callbacks.onSuccess;
        callbacks.onSuccess = function (response, stats, context) {
          console.log(response.data);
          onSuccess(response, stats, context);
        };
     }
      load(context, config, callbacks);
    };
  }
};
```